# how to check whether a row is monotonically increasing or not by ignoring the NaN values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, row

i have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Cell':['A','B','C'],'D1':[5, 2, 3], 'D2':['NaN', 5, 6], 'D3':[7,'NaN', 9], 'D6':[17, 3, 'NaN']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)


Cell  D1   D2   D3   D6
0    A   5  NaN    7   17
1    B   2    5  NaN    3
2    C   3    6    9  NaN
```

i want to check whether D6>D3>D2>D1 by ignoring the NAN values and create a new column 'is_monotonic_increasing' with true or false

```
d1 = {'Cell':['A','B','C'],'D1':[5, 2, 3], 'D2':['NaN', 5, 6], 'D3':[7,'NaN', 9], 'D6':[17, 3, 'NaN'],'is_monotonic_increasing?':['True','False','True']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
print(df1)

    Cell  D1   D2   D3   D6 is_monotonic_increasing?
0    A   5  NaN    7   17          True
1    B   2    5  NaN    3         False
2    C   3    6    9  NaN          True
```

column names that i want to check are dynamic and they can be fetched as list in the program
column_names=[D1,D2,D3,D6]

i tried this

```
df['is_monotonic_increasing?']=df.apply(lambda x:x.is_monotonic_increasing,axis=1)
```

but it is always producing false as output due to NaN.

```
Cell  D1   D2   D3   D6  is_monotonic_increasing?
0    A   5  NaN    7   17                     False
1    B   2    5  NaN    3                     False
2    C   3    6    9  NaN                     False
```

Please let me know any solution to this?

Comment: 'NAN' are strings or np.nan?

Comment: 'NaN'  are introduced by dataframe pivot table

Comment: So it's not a string but np.nan.

Comment: by monotonic increasing, do you mean `<` or `<=`?

Comment: Also is `NaN` the string `'NaN'` or the `np.nan` value? Creation of data indicates the string, but you expect to treat them as `np.nan`.

Comment: @Quang Hoang by monotonic increasing, do you mean < or <= --> it is strictly less than (<)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill forward values to compute the diff along the column axis:

```
df['inc'] = (df.filter(regex='^D\d+').ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1)
               .diff(axis=1).iloc[:, 1:].ge(0).all(axis=1))
print(df)

# Output
  Cell   D1   D2   D3    D6    inc
0    A  5.0  NaN  7.0  17.0   True
1    B  2.0  5.0  NaN   3.0  False
2    C  3.0  6.0  9.0   NaN   True
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution,   d = {'Cell':['A','B','C'],'D1':[5, 2, np.nan], 'D2':[np.nan, 5, 6], 'D3':[7,np.nan, 9], 'D6':[17, 3, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

this fails with the above case when the first column D1 has np.nan

Comment: chain `bfill(axis=1` after `ffill(axis=1)`. solves the first column being NaN

Comment: an extension to this problem--> is it possible to add some tolerance in checking the monotonicity--> like if the diff between the consecutive values is greater than some percentage--> Between 6 and 5 --> ideally it is not monotonically increasing --> i have set the tolerance as 30% --> (6-5)/6=16.3% which is less than 30% --> so i want it to be true-->between 5,3-->(5-3)/5=40% which is greater than 30%--> it will be false-->  i tried to solve this by brute force but i could not come up with solution in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `cummax` and compare with the original value:

```
df['is_monotonic_increasing?'] = (
   ~df.filter(like='D').cummax(axis=1)
      .sub(df).gt(0).any(axis=1)
)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Cell  D1   D2   D3    D6  is_monotonic_increasing?
0    A   5  NaN  7.0  17.0                      True
1    B   2  5.0  NaN   3.0                     False
2    C   3  6.0  9.0   NaN                      True
```