# how to check each row trend with some tolerance by ignoring the np.nan values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, matrix

An extension to this problem
[how to check whether a row is monotonically increasing or not by ignoring the NaN values in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75367459/how-to-check-whether-a-row-is-monotonically-increasing-or-not-by-ignoring-the-na?noredirect=1#comment132988815_75367459)

i have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'Cell':['A','B','C','D','E'],'D1':[5, 2, 2, 6,6], 'D2':[np.nan, 5, 6, np.nan,3], 'D3':[7,np.nan, 5, 5,np.nan], 'D6':[17, 3, np.nan,np.nan,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)


Cell  D1   D2   D3    D6
0    A   5  NaN  7.0  17.0
1    B   2  5.0  NaN   3.0
2    C   2  6.0  5.0   NaN
3    D   6  NaN  5.0   NaN
4    E   6  3.0  NaN   2.0
```

i want to check whether D6>D3>D2>D1(**checking only consecutive pairs,(D1,D2),(D2,D3),(D3,D6)**)  by ignoring the np.nan values with some tolerance added and create two new columns 'is_increasing' with true or false and 'failing pairs'

**Examples**
Between 6 and 5 --> ideally it is not monotonically increasing --> i have set the tolerance as 30% --> (6-5)/6=16.3% --> 5 is 16.3% less than that of 6 which is less than 30% --> **i want it to be true**

Between 5,3-->(5-3)/5=40% which is greater than 30%--> **it will be false**

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    d1 = {'Cell':['A','B','C','D','E'],'D1':[5, 2, 2, 6,6], 'D2':[np.nan, 5, 6, np.nan,3], 'D3':[7,np.nan, 5, 5,np.nan], 'D6':[17, 3, np.nan,np.nan,2],'is_increasing?':['True','False','True','True','False'],'failing pairs':['-','[D2,D6]','-','-','[[D1,D2],[D2,D6]]']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
print(df1)

Cell  D1   D2   D3    D6 is_increasing?       failing pairs
0    A   5  NaN  7.0  17.0                          True                  -
1    B   2  5.0  NaN   3.0                         False            [D2,D6]
2    C   2  6.0  5.0   NaN                          True                  -
3    D   6  NaN  5.0   NaN                          True                  -
4    E   6  3.0  NaN   2.0                         False  [[D1,D2],[D2,D6]]
```

column names that i want to check are dynamic and they can be fetched as list in the program
column_names=[D1,D2,D3,D6]

**Explanation for new columns:**

```
**first row** --> 5,7,17 --> it is increasing 
**second row** --> (2,5)--> increasing, (5,3) --> 1-(3/5)=40% greater than 30% tolerance set --> false
**third row-**-> (2,6)--> increasing, (6,5)--> 1-(5/6)=16.3% less than 30% tolerance set --> true
**fourth row** -->(6,5)--> 1-(5/6)=16.3% less than 30% tolerance set --> true
**fifth row** -->(6,3) --> 1-(3/6)=50% greater than 30% tolerance set,(3,2)=1-(2/3)=33% greater than 30% --> False



   **More examples for the problem statement**
```

i want to check whether trend is increasing or not with tolerance set

**for example**

```
1,3,2,1,4,2,5 ---> i want to take all consecutive pairs and check whether the diff percentage is less than tolerance set 
(1,3) -->1-(3/1)=-200% < 30% --> passed 
(3,2)--> 1-(2/3)=33% > 30% --> failed 
(2,1) -->1-(1/2)=50% > 30% --> failed 
(1,4) --> 1-(4/1)=-400% < 30% --> passed 
(4,2) --> 1-(2/4) = 50% > 30% --> failed 
(2,5) --> 1-(5/2)=-150% < 30% --> passed
```

if any of the pair fails --> trend of increasing is failing with tolerance and i need to make it false with the list of failing pairs

**Example with Nan in between**

```
    2 5 NaN 3 -->(2,5),(5,3) are the pairs that i need to check 
    2 Nan Nan 3 --> (2,3) is the only pair to check 
    2 Nan Nan Nan -->no pairs to check 
    Nan Nan Nan Nan -->no need to check
```

my dataframe size is 500k to 600k rows and i tried brute force by iterating through each row using for loops, it is taking a lot of time.

Please let me know any efficient solution to this as i am newbie to pandas.

Comment: Your method to compute the number of incorrect values is ambiguous. Do you count all prior values as incorrect? If you had 1,3,2,1,4,2,5 what would be the proportion and why? Why not counting just the values that are lower than any previous one?

Comment: i want to check whether trend is increasing or not with tolerance set
1,3,2,1,4,2,5 ---> i want to take all consecutive pairs and check whether the diff percentage is less than tolerance set
(1,3) -->1-(3/1)=-200% < 30%  --> passed
(3,2)--> 1-(2/3)=33% > 30%  --> failed
(2,1) -->1-(1/2)=50% > 30% --> failed
(1,4) --> 1-(4/1)=-400% < 30% --> passed
(4,2) --> 1-(2/4) = 50% > 30% --> failed
(2,5) --> 1-(5/2)=-150% < 30% --> passed
if any of the pair fails --> trend of increasing is failing with tolerance and i need to make it false with the list of failing pairs

Comment: 2  5  NaN   3 -->(2,5),(5,3) are the pairs that i need to check 
2  Nan  Nan   3 --> (2,3) is the only pair to check
2  Nan  Nan   Nan -->no pairs to check 
Nan  Nan  Nan   Nan -->no need to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly the described logic as I believe it is ambiguous.

Here I considered a failing value any value lower that any of the previous ones:

```
df2 = (df.filter(like='D')
         .cummax(axis=1)
         .sub(df)#.gt(0)
       )

m = df2.gt(0)

df['is_increasing?'] = (
 m.sum(axis=1)
       .div(df2.notna().sum(axis=1))
    .le(0.34)
)

df['falling'] = (
    df2.where(m).stack().reset_index()
 .groupby('level_0')['level_1'].agg(list)
 )

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Cell  D1   D2   D3    D6  is_increasing?   falling
0    A   5  NaN  7.0  17.0            True       NaN
1    B   2  5.0  NaN   3.0            True      [D6]
2    C   2  6.0  5.0   NaN            True      [D3]
3    D   6  NaN  5.0   NaN           False      [D3]
4    E   6  3.0  NaN   2.0           False  [D2, D6]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i updated the question with more explanation to remove the ambiguity
df['is_increasing?'] = (
 m.sum(axis=1)
       .div(df2.notna().sum(axis=1))
    .le(0.34)
)
what is this number 0.34?